# Tipo específico para atributos

Tags: python, python-3.x, tipagem

Estou tentando definir o tipo de informação que os atributos recebem, porém não sei bem como fazer. Tentei estes métodos, mas eles não fazem nada.

```
    class Lancamento:
        def __init__(self, tipo, data, descricao, valor, conta,
                     categoria, tag, repeticao, pago):
            self.tipo = tipo
            self.data = data
            self.descricao = descricao
            self._valor = valor
            self.conta = conta
            self.categoria = categoria
            self.tag = tag
            self.repeticao = repeticao
            self.pago = pago

        @property
        def valor(self):
            return self._valor

        @valor.setter
        def valor(self):
            if type(self._valor) != float:
                raise ValueError("...")
#    @valor.setter
#    def valor(self, value):
#        if not isinstance(value, float):
#            print("Precisa ser float")
```

A parte em comentário foi um outro método, que também não retornou o desejado, pois o objeto continua podendo ser construído com qualquer tipo.

Comment: Por que em `__init__` você fez `self._valor = valor` ao invés de `self.valor = valor`? Da segunda maneira você estará utilizando a propriedade que definiu.

Comment: @Woss Se eu ponho self.valor = valor tenho um retorno de self.valor = valor TypeError: valor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Verdade, no seu `setter` faltou um parâmetro. O `setter` de uma propriedade sempre recebe dois parâmetros: o `self` e o novo valor da propriedade que foi atribuído, assim como fez no código comentado.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, dentro da construção da classe  <code> if valor < 0: raise ValueError("Não pode ser negativo")    elif not isinstance(valor, float):    raise ValueError("Precisa ser float")    else:    self._valor = valor </code> @Woss

Comment: Não era mais simples corrigir a propriedade?

Comment: Eu comecei a programar em python recentemente, e o material que eu encontrei para solucionar esse problema não gerou o resultado esperado, somente essa solução mesmo. Nem mesmo o direcionamento que me foi proposto aqui (e que eu marquei como resposta) foi efetivo para solucionar o problema.